# Converting datediff to Azure Mapping Data flows expression language

Tags: azure-data-factory, expression, azure-mapping-data-flow

I need to convert this sql snippet to Azure Data Flow expression language:

"case when Trans_StatusId <> 1 then 0 else datediff(day, AppliedDate, getdate()) end"

I tried "iif(Trans_StatusId  != 1, 0, subDays(currentTimestamp(), toDate(AppliedDate)))"

but I am getting the error "subDays' expects 'integral' type of argument"

Converting AppliedDate to integer may be expected but it's not logical to convert a timestamp to and int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subDays()` function returns the date value by subtracting the number of days from the date in the first argument. Therefore, instead of using the `subDays()` function, you can follow the below approach.
Take the `currentDate()` function to get the current date and the `toDate` function to convert "AppliedDate" to a date. Then, you can subtract the two dates to get the difference in days.

Below is the ADF data flow expression to achieve the required value.

```
iif(Trans_StatusId != 1, 0, datediff(currentDate(), toDate(AppliedDate)))
```

**Source data preview:**

[image]

**Derived column Transformation:**

The equivalent expression of the given SQL code is provided in the derived column transformation. Below is the output.

[image: gif1]